# java script guessing between 100 and 0

Tags: javascript

hello i am very new to coding and i have no clue on how this codes does not work.

what i need to do is make a random number(the test value is 20) from 0 to 100 and store it in a value then the user must guess it if its higher then the random value the code will say to high and if too lower then it will say to low and if they type -1 or get the number right the code will then break and stop the loop

the problem: i dont know how to loop the code back to the start so it can ask the user the same question

the code its self:

```
     var min = 0
 var max = 100
var roll = 20
function start() {
    println("hello pick a num between 0 and 100 type -1 if you wanna quit")
    var roll = 20
    var userguess = readInt("what is your guess: ")
    while(userguess > min){
    if (userguess > roll){
     println("too high you ")
    }
   if (userguess < roll){
        println("to low ")
    }
    if(userguess == -1 ){
        println(" you quit")
        break;
    }
    if(userguess == roll ){
        println("wait you got it ")
        break;
    }
}
     
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing JavaScript with Java. They are two different languages. Your code appears to be Java.

Comment: no it is java script

Comment: There are no native functions called `readInt` and `println` in JavaScript. That's Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to the coding world.

In this case, you can use **Recursive Functions**. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than my answer.

I'll just implement your requirements.

```
var min = 0
var max = 100
var roll = 20
function start(min, max, roll) {
  println("hello pick a num between 0 and 100 type -1 if you wanna quit")
  var userguess = readInt("what is your guess: ")
  if(userguess == -1 ) {
    println("you quit")
    return "User exited";
  }
  if(userguess == roll ) {
    println("wait you got it")
    return userguess;
  }
  if(userguess < min && userguess > max) {
    println("out of range")
    return start(min, max, roll)
  }
  if (userguess > roll){
    println("too high you")
    return start(min, max, roll)
  }
  if (userguess < roll){
    println("to low")
    return start(min, max, roll)
  }
}
```